# How to Use ClickableSpans in a TextView and still be able to scroll horizontally?

Tags: java, android, textview

I have some code which uses a textview with a linkmovementmethod so that individual words can be clicked.

However, what I really need is a scrollingmovementmethod. When I do that, the individual spanned segments are no longer clickable.

Unfortunately this means it uses a vertical scroll, even though horizontal scroll ( `android:scrollHorizontally="true"`) is specified.

I'm trying to figure out how to retain the ability to catch onClick on the individual span words, and still allow it to be vertically scrollable.

Can someone provide advice on how to get the best of both worlds?

```
    String page = getPage();
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    textView.setText(page, BufferType.SPANNABLE);


    Spannable ssPage = (Spannable) textView.getText();
    Integer[] indices = getSpaceIndices(textView.getText().toString(), ' ');

    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
      // to cater last/only word loop will run equal to the length of indices.length
    for (int i = 0; i <= indices.length; i++) {
        ClickableSpan clickSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View widget) {
                TextView tv = (TextView) widget;
                String s = tv
                        .getText()
                        .subSequence(tv.getSelectionStart(),
                                tv.getSelectionEnd()).toString();
                Log.d("called", s);
                Speak (s);

                //textView.scrollBy(tv.getWidth(), tv.getHeight());
            }

            public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
                 super.updateDrawState(ds);
                 ds.setUnderlineText(false);
            }
        };
       // to cater last/only word
        end = (i < indices.length ? indices[i] : ssPage.length());
        ssPage.setSpan(clickSpan, start, end,
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        start = end + 1;
    }
```

Layout:

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:alpha="245"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:paddingBottom="15dip"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"

    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textColorLink="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="20dip"
    tools:context=".ReadActivity" />
```

Comment: Im not understanding, are you scrolling horizontal or vertical?

Comment: I configured it to scroll horizontally however it does no scroll due to the link movement.  

The layout is in the original post.

Answer (score -1):

[LinkMovementMethod](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/LinkMovementMethod.html) already "traverses links in the text buffer and scrolls if necessary." so you can use it if you want both clickable links and scrollable views.

Then you have to adjust the textview's layout like this:

```
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

By setting `maxLines`, the excess lines after it, will exceed the height, thus resulting in a scrollable textview.